# CSS class not being used

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We're using bootstrap and I've got a page where I'm getting conflicting results with small buttons.

I have a number of buttons that look like this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-small" value="Save"... />
```

I have my main form and then some divs that are used for jQuery dialogs. On the main form, the buttons are showing up as small, but in the dialogs, the buttons are showing up regular size, even though in all cases, I'm using `<input type="button"` and `class="btn btn-small"`. The only difference is the divs that contain them, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the styles applied somewhere above the buttons.

When I look at the "Computed" styles in Firebug, it shows `.btn` being applied, but `.btn-small` has a line through it for every property I've inspected that has both listed, implying it's not being used.

[image]

The small buttons have a line height of 15px, but the normal size have a line height of 20px. What's really odd is, even though the computed property for line height for the small buttons say 15px, when I expand it to see where it comes from, it shows `.btn` with a 20px value being applied (see image).

[image: button line height property]

The bottom line is I'm really not sure what's causing it. I'm assuming it's some style in one of the many divs surrounding it. My main question is obviously how do I fix this, but on a more general level, what would cause the `.btn-small` style to not be used?

Comment: Any chance you could create a working example in jsfiddle.net or provide a link to the actual site?

Comment: "implying it's not being used." Typically that means the style is being overridden by another rule somewhere, not that it's being ignored or not used.

Comment: Are both `btn` and `btn-small` declaring a line-height? Try removing it from `btn`. It is also easier if you develop without a minified CSS file.

Comment: My gut feel is that while opening the dialog javascript is only adding btn and not adding the extra btn-small. try seeing this in the chrome for the class names. sometimes firebug acts weird when javascript is involved.  it would be great if you can put the styles (not computed) of both cases in a pastebin.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I've tried to create a small example in jsFiddle, but I've been unable to reproduce the problem with simpler examples. The page where this happens is fairly complex.

Comment: @SrinivasYedhuri Javascript isn't adding the classes. They're hard-coded in the html.

Comment: @jalynn2 Did I say that? I don't think I did. And I don't think the solution is going to be for me to change the Bootstrap css.

Comment: @Pete: No you didn't say that, but that is what it looks like from the little snippets of info you have provided in Firebug snapshots. As I said, earlier, get a non-minified version of the CSS and use it temporarily. Then Firebug will show you what line each property is coming from, instead of saying everything comes from line 9. I agree that you don't  want to change an 3rd party CSS (I didn't realize it was 3rd party), so you need to see why you are misapplying the styles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to track down the problem. I initially ruled out jQuery-UI interaction since I was unable to reproduce it in jsFiddle by using jQuery-UI. What I hadn't mentioned and turned out to be relevant, is that we are also using Infragistics Ignite toolset. Ignite is based on jQuery-UI. The dialog was getting the .ui-widget class (I was focused on the button's classes) and that was causing ignite to set the font size in the buttons which then broke the Bootstrap sizing.

To fix the issue, I removed the following line from infragistic's .css file:

```
.ui-widget input,.ui-widget select,.ui-widget textarea,.ui-widget button{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1em}
```

Sorry for not providing all the relevant info. Just didn't think of infragistics as being a possible cause since I wasn't directly using any of their stuff on that page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements can be assigned multiple classes by listing the classes in the class attribute, with a blank space to separate them however if the same property is declared in both rules, the conflict is resolved first through specificity, then according to the order of the CSS declarations. The order of classes in the class attribute is not relevant. [paraphrased from mozilla common css questions]

You have two classes modifying the same attribute, and so the browser rightly only applies one.

Comment: But this ignores the claim that within the same page, two identical buttons have different styles applied.

Comment: You likely have a parent div or container which ALSO has a class or default styling, which conflicts with the above two classes. Share more code and let's see :).

Comment: I'm aware of how CSS styles work. According to the Bootstrap documentation (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons), you make a small button by giving both "btn" and "btn-small" classes to the button, so I'm assuming there's nothing intentionally conflicting in their style. I'm fairly certain this has to do with the divs above the buttons and not the button styles themselves. Otherwise this would be a fairly common bootstrap complaint.

Comment: Yep I agree (my comment agrees with that), but we can't help unless we know what those divs look like.Currently to us the only code on your page is <input type="button" class="btn btn-small" value="Save"... /> repeated a few times, some bootstrap css, there are divs wrapping around these inputs but we have no knowledge of what is in them or what classes or styling they might have.